# Creating symlink while partition is not mounted

Tags: linux, mount, symbolic-link, veracrypt

I currently have an encrypted partition on my Linux (elementary OS), which contains most of my data. I mount it into `/media/veracrypt2/`manually at each start-up, but sometimes I just don't need it.

The fact is that my download folder in Firefox points to `/media/veracrypt2/Downloads`, and I would like Firefox to download my files into `~/Downloads/` when my encrypted partition is not mounted. I thought I could make a symlink from one folder to the other one while the partition is not mounted, but I have no idea of how I could do this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply create the symlink in the parent device (probably your root filesystem).

Try this (as root, or use sudo):

- unmount your crypted partition:

  ```
  sudo umount /media/veracrypt2/
  ```
- then make a symlink to your download dir:

  ```
  sudo ln -s ~/Downloads /media/veracrypt2/Downloads
  ```

The symlink is then visible when your crypted partition is not mounted, so Firefox should be happy. When mounted, the "real" Downloads dir is seen.